# can a .net 3.5 compiled app run on a machine with only .net 2.0?

Tags: .net, clr

Answer seems obvious but thought id ask ... don't have a 2.0 machine handy

Comment: Also, if all your syntax is 2.0 - compatible, then you should be able to target a 2.0 platform for a particular project.

Answer (score 3):

If the app only uses the 2.0 libraries, and only features from the 2.0 *versions* of the libraries, yes.

If it uses 3.x features like WPF, WCF or LINQ, then no.